# react native android ask camera permission when user first logs in

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, user-permissions

I'm not familiar with the react-native app permissions for android and ios. I'm in thihs project which needs camera and audio permissions for videocalls that are already implemented and work fine.

The thing is that currently these permissions are asked the first time the users enters a videocall and that causes delay and bugs on the videocall flow. I'd like to aks these permissions the first time the users opens the app (they enter first to their profile or the dashboard, the videocall part happens afterwards), like I've seen other apps do.

This is the androidManifest.xml file that handles the permissions. I looked for a way to change when they're asked but I couldn't find anything on the format I'm currently at, and since it's new to me I don't want to change the behaviour completely by accident.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rectnativetemplate">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="dev--b45llct.us.auth0.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/android/${applicationId}/callback"
                android:scheme="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

------------

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is there a way to ask the permissions when the user first enters the app? And if it's possible, how can I implement the same behaviour on IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request` from [PermissionsAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid).

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  console.log('Camera permission granted');
} else {
  console.log('Camera permission denied');
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for its use? Where and how I can call this method?

Comment: I found one, thanks it worked!